# Sonata Favico won't change

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I recently began a new Symfony 2.7 project and i wanted to add a back office to it so i choosed sonata admin to save some time.

The whole thing is functionnal but i stumble acrosse a detail that drives me mad.

The favico won't change, even worst even after i have deleted it from the project folders it stay the same without the file.

I juste don't understand why the old favico stay when it should use the new one i have put in my web folder..

Does anyone know how to change the sonata admin Favico ?

thank you for reading.

Comment: This needs more detail to be answerable: where is the current favicon located? What happens if you call it directly in your browser? Have you tried a different browser, to see whether it is a caching issue? Is there a link to the favicon in the HTML?

Comment: Did you do `php app/console cache:clear`?

Comment: Yes i  cache clear the whole thing,

Answer (score 1):

just override the stylesheet of sonata admin
first create new view

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {{ parent() }}
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="{{ asset('assets/images/favicon.ico') }}">
    {% endblock %}
```

then you need to add in your config.yml

```
sonata_admin:
templates:
    layout:               '@Back/override/standard_layout_stylesheet.html.twig'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install and dump assets then clear the cache of the Browser.

1. php app/console assets:install
2. php app/console assetic:dump
3. CTRL + F5 on Windows or go to History option and clear it there.